# Change interview location of US B2 visa

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas

I am applying for tourist visa for my parents. In DS-160, I selected the location to be India-Kolkata. However, when I am trying to schedule the interview date and time from here: https://cgifederal.secure.force.com/?language=English&country=India, it defaults the Post of Interview to Hyderabad.

How do we change the interview location to Kolkata ? I understand that it's not an issue to have different interview locations mentioned in DS-160 and in the interview appointment application. But for personal reasons, it would be easier for my parents to travel to Kolkata and hence I want to change the Post of Interview to Kolkata in the visa interview application.

I am not able to find the place to change the Post of Interview. The below image is not from DS-160. It's while filling up the application form for scheduling the visa interview.

[image]

Any pointers would be really great.

Comment: were you able to change the interview location from Hyderabad to Kolkata, I am also in the same situation, is there any solution for this? I have not submitted the application yet.

Comment: yes, actually, when you are filling up DS-160, there is no way to change your post of interview. As a matter of fact, te post of interview that you see in the screenshot above is just for FYI purposes only which in my opinion is very misleading. Once you pay and get the receipts and book the interview slot, at that point in time you would be able to select the actual interview location.

Comment: @rahul, did you find out how to change the location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the screenshot above, the interview location was defaulting to Hyderabad. Also, at this point of time, I had not paid the visa fees. So once you make the payment and get the receipt, the next step is to actually select the location of interview for both biometrics and consulate visa interview.

It's confusing because the website defaults to a location and there is no way to even change it.

Answer (score 2):

From [Quora:](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-change-Location-of-the-Visa-Interview-Place-after-submitting-the-DS-160-form)

> Yes, you can change the location of the visa interview appointment after submitting the DS-160 form. You don't have to fill the DS-160 form again for a change in consulate.

From [immihelp:](https://www.immihelp.com/us-visa/appointment-faq.html)

> You can log into the system using your passport number, date of birth and country of citizenship, you can select cancel or reschedule appointment from the options on the Applicant Summary page. You can change the appointment date (cancel, reschedule) as many times as you need before the deadline for doing so.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clearer. Could you please help me out here.

Comment: @RahulDevMishra is there an option to change it?

Comment: That's what I am trying to find out. Hyderabad was selected by default. I do not see any page or a placeholder to select the interview location. I would be very surprised if there isn't any option to change the default location of interview