# How to choose country in which to have U.S. visa interview?

Tags: visas, usa, embassies

I am applying for a J1 visa to the US. I want to do the interview in the Czech republic. I am a Czech citizen so even though I don't live there, it should not be an issue. So I go to this webpage [1] and I click on "log in" (green button on the right). However, that sends me to a webpage "APPLY FOR A U.S. VISA in  Denmark" (I am currently in Denmark). How do I change the country of my interview?

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129652/change-interview-location-of-us-b2-visa) asks about something similar, but within one country. Another problem is that I think I may be eligible to get a visa without an interview in the Czech republic but the form then asks me about Denmark when it needs to ask about the Czech Republic, so that answer is not applicable.

[1] https://www.ustraveldocs.com/cz/

Comment: Did you previously create an account for Denmark? Maybe you need to create a new account for the Czech Republic?

Comment: WTF I thought this is a scammer but it's not.

Comment: @chx I had started to write that it wasn’t an official site but then realised it was. Definitely doesn’t look like it, but it is…

Comment: ustraveldocs.com is run by CGI Federal, who are the US government contractor responsible for the logistics of US visa processing in dozens of countries around the world.  The site is very much legitimate.

Comment: @Doc it's totally legit but the name is dodgy AF.

Comment: Having an official government website use `.com` instead of `.gov` in a field where there are a sea of scam websites seems like a truly bizarre decision.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you create an account on the ustraveldocs.com website it create a profile for you which is tied to a specific country. You will only be able to create visa appointments in the country registered in your profile.

You can find the country that your profile is currently configured for by logging into the website, and looking at the top of the main page - it will show "Apply for a U.S Visa" followed by "in [country]".  eg:

[image]

If you reach out to CGI Federal (the company that runs that website on behalf of the US Government) support they will be able to change the country in your profile, and you will be able to book an appointment in the new country.

Alternatively you can create a new account using a different email address, although when I went through this process with CGI Federal several years ago they recommended against taking this approach.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to solve it at last. When I tried registering a new account under the same email address, it did not work. I have thus created a new account with a new email address and it went through. Thank to jcaron for suggesting this.